# Requiring SSL with WCF causes "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'" error?

Tags: wcf, ssl, client, wcf-client, anonymous

We have a WCF service hosted in IIS that a client dll is trying to access.  The service is bound in IIS to use HTTPS and is set to ignore client certificates, which works just fine, but requiring SSL is causing a problem.

The thing that I really don't understand is that calling one of the service's methods works just fine, but calling another method does NOT work and I get the following error: "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

What could be causing this?  I am pretty new to WCF, so please let me know if I am missing anything or if there is any more information that is needed.

Here is some of the service configuration code:

```
this.Description.Behaviors.Add(new FaultConversionErrorHandler());
this.Description.Behaviors.Add(new LoggingErrorHandler());

BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

ServiceEndpoint endpoint = this.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILicenseService), binding, String.Empty);

SecurityEndpointBehavior securityEndpointBehavior = new SecurityEndpointBehavior();
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(securityEndpointBehavior);
```

And here is how the client references the service:

```
EndpointAddress a = new EndpointAddress(licenseServiceUrl);
Binding b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);

LicenseServiceClient client = new LicenseServiceClient(b, a);
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SecurityEndpointBehavior());
```

Comment: I faced a close problem with you ( [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979346/wcf-service-stop-responding-unexpectedly-with-error-client-authentication-schem) )
Did you solved your problem? If yes, can you help me to solve mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by changing your binding info.
Set TransportClientCredential Type to certificate to use required certificate in IIS SSL settings.

If it is Ws-Http it's a bit different. WCF WS-service host is actually checking if the incoming client request certificate is present in Trusted People.
So the remote certificate should present in the server's trusted people.

Or add CustomValidator and override the behavior.