# WCF Service stop responding unexpectedly with error "client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Tags: wcf, iis-7, sql-server-2012, client-certificates, windows-server-2012

we developed a WCF service ( running on windows server 2012) and client API which are connected each other with client certificate authentication.
They were running cool up to we made a stress test on system.
We try to load system with giant data then the system responds so slowly. So we interrupt the process and try to clear DB. The clearing and reindexing DB took more than 6 hours.
After that the WCF service stoped responding! But we did not change any code block!
Therefore, I think that the error is not caused by our code.

the error message that wcf client get when try to connect service is below

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
>   request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
>   HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

I found a similar [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240160/requiring-ssl-with-wcf-causes-the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authen) which is so close to my question. ( [Requiring SSL with WCF causes "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240160/requiring-ssl-with-wcf-causes-the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authen))

What can be the problem? and What can be the solution?
Is there any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure of the situation in your case, but once such thing happened with me in developent environment and after analysis i found that whatever settings I did on IIS (7.5) for hosting my service got reset. I also didn't do any change, just did iisreset and it stopped working. I reconfigured IIS for my service and everything worked fine. try checking that.

Comment: I know it's been quite a while, but did you get to find out anything about it? I have a similar issue.